# What Do the @ mean inside these comments ?

Tags: php, comments

I am reading some PHP code from someone else and the file is filled comments preceeding each meathod. What does the comment @access and @var mean ?

```
/**
 * EE Superobject
 *
 * @access      private
 * @var         object
 */
private $EE;
```

Many Thanks !

Comment: docblock tags - used for documenting the class/methods/properties in a manner that can generate automated documentation using PHPDocumentor or similar; and can also be picked up by IDEs for autocompletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically used by [`phpDocuemntor`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html) to compile documentation.

> phpDocumentor tags are very similar to tags for the JavaDoc tool for Sun's Java Programming Language. Tags are only parsed if they are the first thing on a new line of a DocBlock. You may use the @ character freely throughout documents as long as it does not begin a new line. An example:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * tags demonstration
>  * @author this tag is parsed, but this @version tag is ignored
>  * @version 1.0 this version tag is parsed
>  */
> ```
>
> Here is a list of the standard tags:
>
> ```
> @access
> @author
> @copyright
> @deprecated
> @example
> @ignore
> @internal
> @link
> @see
> @since
> @tutorial
> @version
> inline {@internal}}
> inline {@inheritdoc}
> inline {@link}
> ```

Comment: This is not specific to PHPDoc, there are numerous documentation generators that utilize this.

Answer (score 4):

It's an annotation used by some documentation generating tools to generate said documentation.

Answer (score 0):

These are PHPDoc tags: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc they are used to describe certain properties of a class or function; the documentation is automatically generated from the comments above class/functions.

Comment: This is not specific to PHPDoc, there are numerous documentation generators that utilize this.

Comment: @crypticツ I meant PHPDoc as a format, not as a tool. Indeed that format is supported by numerous generators, which is a good thing. I guess "docblocks" would be a more appropriate name, though I think that "PHPDoc tags" is more explicit.